# Add background pattern to a png image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

As the title says, i want to add background pattern to a png image(not the whole canvas). I tried various guides but they are all about adding background pattern to whole canvas by either using `background-image` css property or by using canvas's `createPattern` method.

[This](http://catherineasanov.com/sml123/html/DS/index.php) is what i'm creating.

As you can see, there are various png images on the canvas(left arm, right arm, body, etc.) and they are all customizable. Now i want to add repeat-pattern to those png images. Those repeat pattern would be an image itself.

How to do that via svg, fabric or any other method?

Comment: Draw the image on the canvas than draw addinal patterns?

Comment: @Luba 

Image is already on the canvas. How to draw additional patterns on that image?

Comment: Create your pattern and use var destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d'); destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);

Comment: Or put an image instead of sourceCanvas

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way is to create a `FOR` loop to draw your PNG images at the size you need.

- Use the *canvas width/height* values,your *image size* and your *preferred image distance* to determine
  the *number of iterations* your loop needs to run.
- On each iteration increment a distance variable a certain value in
  order to blit your image at an increasing distance on the x/y axis.

When the loop ends you will have a pattern.

Comment: Can you provide an example? That would be very helpful.

Comment: sure thing - can you give me an image size and a distance between the images?

Comment: I'm trying to implement it here: http://catherineasanov.com/sml123/html/DS/index.php. Left arm's size is 101px X 325px.